# Guide for windows programmer converting to mac

Tags: .net, macos, mono

I'm a windows programmer with lots of experience building apps in .net, and I'm currently trying to get my hands dirty doing some hacking on the mac.  I'm interested in using mono and specifically using monomac to ease the transition by staying in the warm, cosy and familiar .net environment.  However, I'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around all the mac-specific apis, libraries and tools, such as interface builder, xibs, file's owner, first responder, *kit, and all the other-worldly mac weirdness.  I've been on one platform for too long and my brain is locked into a particular view.  To anyone who has blazed this path before me, could you recommend any books to read to get me up to speed?  Ideally I'd love to read a detailed comparison of the windows vs mac apis, tools and libraries, to help me with the translation.  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What's usually missing is the "I really care" bit.  You'll have to buy an i product and genuinely like it first.  Destroy your Android devices to get in the mood.

Comment: @mathepic IMO different OSes have so different conventions that you need to adapt most non trivial programs to the target platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a Windows convert as well (from MFC/C++, not .NET) and I highly recommend [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619).